# Gatsby.js default starter site not updating on typography.js changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm learning Gatsby.js throught their tutorial.

I'm at the point of using typography.js, but my site is not taking the stuff that I write in the typography.js file.

They say in the tutorial:

> with the default starter, you’ll need to delete the default layout.css
>   used by that starter as it overrides the Typography.js CSS
>   https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-two/

The thing is: where do I find the default "layout.css"?

Thanks!

Matteo

My git repo  [here](https://github.com/matteocarpi/tutorial-part-two)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs state:

> Stop gatsby develop by typing `Ctrl + c` into the terminal window where the development process has been running. Then, run `gatsby develop` again to restart it. This will allow your plugin change to take effect.

However, I found that you need to run `gatsby build` first, before running `gatsby develop` again in order to see any of those changes made to the `Typography.js` options.